# Is it better to save data as Object of Objects or Array of Arrays of Objects into NoSQL(MongoDB) database?

Tags: json, typescript, mongodb, nosql, deno

I have a code like below:

```
export type Params = NonNullable<ConstructorParameters<typeof URLSearchParams>[0]>;

class AlphaVantage { constructor (protected readonly api: AlaphaVantage) {} }

class Forex extends AlphaVantage {
  rate (from_currency: string, to_currency: string) {
    return this.api.query({
      function: 'CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE',
      from_currency,
      to_currency,
    });
  }
}

class Stocks extends AlphaVantage {
    intraday (symbol: string , outputsize: string) {
      return this.api.query({
        function: 'TIME_SERIES_DAILY',
        symbol,
        outputsize,
      });
    }
  }

export class AlaphaVantage {
  #token: string;

  constructor (token: string) {
    this.#token = token;
  }

  async query <Result = any>(params: Params): Promise<Result> {
    const url = new URL('https://www.alphavantage.co/query');

    const usp = new URLSearchParams(params);
    usp.set('apikey', this.#token);
    url.search = usp.toString();

    const request = new Request(url.href);
    const response = await fetch(request );

    if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Response not OK');

    return response.json();
  }

  forex = new Forex(this);
  stocks = new Stocks(this);
}

export const stockServerFetch = async () => {
  const YOUR_API_KEY = 'ASLDVIWXGEWFWNZG';
  const alpha = new AlaphaVantage('ASLDVIWXGEWFWNZG');
  const fetchedStock = await alpha.stocks.intraday('MSFT', 'compact' ).then((data: any) => {return data["Time Series (Daily)"]} );
   return fetchedStock;

 }

const rawSummaryKeys = ['1. open', '2. high', '3. low', '4. close', '5. volume'] as const;
type RawSummaryKey = typeof rawSummaryKeys[number];

const parsedSummaryKeys = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'] as const;
type ParsedSummaryKey = typeof parsedSummaryKeys[number];

const rawToParsedSummaryKeyMapping: Record<RawSummaryKey, ParsedSummaryKey> = {
  '1. open': 'open',
  '2. high': 'high',
  '3. low': 'low',
  '4. close': 'close',
  '5. volume': 'volume',
};

/** Values are parsable as numbers */
type RawSummary = Record<RawSummaryKey, string>;

/** Keys are dates in format: YYYY-MM-DD */
type DailyRawSummaries = Record<string, RawSummary>;

type ParsedSummary = Record<ParsedSummaryKey, string>;

function parseRawSummary (summary: RawSummary): ParsedSummary {
  const parsed = {} as ParsedSummary;
  for (const key of rawSummaryKeys) {
    // If the "volume" number ever exceeds Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
    // then you can switch to using BigInts
    parsed[rawToParsedSummaryKeyMapping[key]] = String(summary[key]);
  }
  return parsed;
}

type DailySummaryEntrry = [date: string, summary: ParsedSummary];

function parseDailySummaries (summaries: DailyRawSummaries): DailySummaryEntrry[] {
  const entries: DailySummaryEntrry[] = [];

  for (const date in summaries) {
    const rawSummary = summaries[date];
    if (!rawSummary) continue;
    entries.push([date, parseRawSummary(rawSummary)]);
  }
  console.log(entries);

  return entries.sort().reverse(); // sort by newest date first
}

type stocksData = [ name : string, stock : DailySummaryEntrry[] ];

export const saveStockData = async()=> {
  const json = await stockServerFetch();
  const parsed = parseDailySummaries(json);
  const newStockData : DailySummaryEntrry[] = [];
  const newStockDataWithName : stocksData[] = [];

  for (const [date, summary] of parsed) {
     newStockData.push([date, summary ]);
  }
  newStockDataWithName.push(['MSFT' , newStockData]);

}


stockServerFetch();
saveStockData();
```

This code downloads stock data from AlphaVantage server. Then after some modification the result of `newStockDataWithName` would be like the following:

```
[
  [
    "MSFT",
    [
      [ "2022-03-11", [Object] ],
      [ "2022-03-10", [Object] ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

And if I want to add more stocks together with the above code, it will be like this:

```
[
 [
   [
     "AAPL",
     [
       [ "2022-03-11", [Object] ],
       [ "2022-03-10", [Object] ]
     ] 
   ]
 ],
   [
     [
       "MSFT",
       [
         [ "2022-03-11", [Object] ],
         [ "2022-03-10", [Object] ]
       ]
     ]
   ]
]
```

`[Object]`s are something like this:

```
{
  open: "174.1400",
  high: "175.4800",
  low: "171.5500",
  close: "172.1200",
  volume: "90865899"
}
```

But I don't know if this is a good idea to save such a array into the MongoDB or it's better to convert it to an Object format like the following?

```
{ 'AAPL' :
  { '2022-03-11' : {        
      'open' : "287.9600", 
      'high': "289.5100", 
      'low' : "279.4300",  
     'close' : "280.0700",
     'volume' : "27209330"
  },
    '2022-03-10' : {       
    'open' : "283.0200",
    'high' : "286.6000",
    'low' : "280.5800",
    'close' : "285.5900",
    'volume' : "30628012"
   }
  },
  'MSFT' :
  { '2022-03-11' : {        
      'open' : "287.9600", 
      'high': "289.5100", 
      'low' : "279.4300",  
     'close' : "280.0700",
     'volume' : "27209330"
  },
    '2022-03-10' : {       
    'open' : "283.0200",
    'high' : "286.6000",
    'low' : "280.5800",
    'close' : "285.5900",
    'volume' : "30628012"
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it is a bad design anyway. Dynamic field name are usually difficult to handle. In your queries you will have to deal a lot with `$arrayToObject` and `$objectToArray`. And you should **never** store date values as strings, use always proper `Date` Objects. I would rather suggest: `currency: {id: "AAPL", [{date: ISODate("2022-03-10"), open: ..., high: ...} , {date: ISODate("2022-03-11"), open: ..., high: ...}] }`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: Thank you. So you say it's always better to store data as numeric values instead of string if it is possible?

Comment: Yes, you should always use the correct data type. Imagine you like to get "where close value < open value" with `open: "995.47", close: "1002.63"` Your query will fail.